# Print description in XCode shows the correct value, using the variable shows wrong value

Tags: ios, xcode, json, parsing, integer

I'm working on a JSON response from a server, and in the response data, among other things, should be a "credits" property, which is an int, which should have the value of 2000. However, if I try to use this property, I get a value like 180988576. But, if I "print description" of the property from the debugger, it says:

```
Printing description of playerData->_credits:
2000
```

How do I access this value?

Comment: show the code by which you are trying to print

Comment: self.lblBalance.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",playerData.credits];

Comment: are your sure credits is of type int/nsinteger and not a pointer to integer. as the value(180988576) might be of pointer.

Comment: well, when i type playerData.credits, the auto-complete window shows the credits property as int, but maybe you are right. If so how do I access the value?

Comment: can you show the Class declaration of playerData

Comment: Also, in the declaration of the properties, I can see that the property is not a pointer, as it does not have an asterix *

Comment: interface PlayerDataResponse : Response

property (nonatomic, assign) int playerUID;
property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *userName;
property (nonatomic, assign) int credits;

end<code>

Comment: yes it is not a pointer. Therefore I am not able to help you, unless i see your full code, if you are comfortable to send me your codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have to do is , When you are fetching the value from JSON

use like this :

`[[JSON ObjectForKey:@"Key"]integerValue];`

It will give you the correct result. Try it once. You can assign that value to an integer variable.

Comment: int credits = [[JSON ObjectForKey:@"Key"]intValue]; will also work